In Vasicek/ASRF default equation, why doesn't a Z=0 lead to TTC = PiT?

Consider the vasicek/asrf model for relating the acyclical risk of a obligor defaulting (PD TTC) to its point-in-time risk (PD PIT) given a state in economic cycle Z and rho.
Z is from standard-normal distribution, such that 0 reflects a neutral economy (neither good nor bad).
Assuming Z =0, and rho >0, PiT PD would be less than TTC PD for all rational values [0,1].
My question is not about the maths per se, I understand the derivation behind this - but how do we rationalise this? surely default risk in a neutral economy should converge to the long-run average (assuming default risk is symmetrically distributed across a cycle)?
thanks

Is this an actual programming-related question? Please have a look the [tour] and [ask]
